# How to call WCF Ria Service/DomainService from Jquery?

Tags: jquery, wcf, ria

I'm attempting to call a DomainService created using WCF Ria Services from jquery.  If I use a POST I get 405 method not allowed. If I use Get, it get javascript errors.  Am I missing a configuration step? This code results in the 405.

```
    function GetSearchResults() {
        $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Services/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomerSearchResults",
        data: '{"customerId":1}',
        timeout: 5000,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: Success,
        error: Fail
    });
    }

[EnableClientAccess]
public class CustomerService : DomainService
{
    public List<CustomerSearchResult> GetCustomerSearchResults(string customerId)
    {


        var list = new List<CustomerSearchResult>();
        list.Add(new CustomerSearchResult
            {
              Id = 1,
                                   Name = "Me"
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
```

}

Comment: What sort of Javascript errors are you getting on GET?

Comment: can I see how you define your web service method?

Comment: The javascript error is basically, when accessing the properties of the deserialized json object, that the object is hasn't been deserialized.  
 'ResultCount' is null or not an object

Comment: OP found the answer here: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2011/04/13/RIAJS-jQuery-client-for-WCF-RIA-Services.aspx (originally posted by @Amitabh).